# How to reduce compilation time by using for loop

Tags: r

I have the below R code .

**OBJECTIVE :** I am trying to check strings present in **kind** object is composite of **word** object by iterating & comparing the character positioning of the two objects. If it is composite of the other ,it returns POSITIVE else NEGATIVE.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT :**

If kind object value has minimal characters in each string **c('abcde','crnas','onarous','ravus')** it gives me better response. If the strings present in the kind object has more string length ( 10 ^ 5) **c('cdcdc.....{1LCharacters}','fffw....{1LCharacters}','efefefef..{1LCharacters}')**. It takes more time to process. Is there a better way to put this in , so that compilation time can be relatively small.

Suggestions / Corrections are highly appreciated.

```
word <- "coronavirus"
total <- "3"
kind <- c('abcde','crnas','onarous','ravus')

invisible(lapply(kind,function(x) {

    if (length(x) > length(word)) {
    cat("NEGATIVE",sep='\n') 
    }
    index=1;
    for (i in seq(from=1,to=nchar(word)-1,by=1)) {
    
                    
        if(substr(word,i,i) == substr(x,index,index))
        {
          index<-index+1;
        }           

    }
    if (index == nchar(x))
    {
        cat("POSITIVE",sep='\n')
    }
    else
    {
      cat("NEGATIVE",sep='\n')   
    }   
}))
```

**Output :**

```
NEGATIVE
POSITIVE
NEGATIVE
POSITIVE
```

Comment: first n your example, length(x) and length(word) will both always be 1. so why compare them? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Onyambu i am trying to check the words present in kind object is compostion of word object. You can ignore that piece of line length(x) and length(word) comaprsion.

Comment: @Onyambu I have updated the code and problem statement.

Comment: I believe the answers provided below are sufficient. Choose the best one and accept it as the answer

Comment: “compilation” refers to something very specific in the context of programming languages, and is unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

If you want to print the result vertically, you can try `cat` like below

```
cat(
  paste0(c("NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE")[
    1 +
      sapply(
        gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", ".*", kind, perl = TRUE),
        grepl,
        x = word
      )
  ], collapse = "\n"),
  "\n"
)
```

which gives

```
NEGATIVE
POSITIVE
NEGATIVE
```

---

I guess you can try `gsub` + `grepl` like below

```
c("NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE")[
  1 +
    sapply(
      gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", ".*", kind, perl = TRUE),
      grepl,
      x = word
    )
]
```

which gives

```
[1] "NEGATIVE" "POSITIVE" "NEGATIVE"
```

Comment: Hi Thomas how do i get output value one below the other with no other mentions.                                    NEGATIVE
POSITIVE
NEGATIVE

Comment: Thanks for the code.  : ) . If i pass input like this input <- c("coronavirus.*", "2", "c.*","ravus") . It throws me an error. Any idea how to handle special character as well

Comment: @ChennaiCheetah Then you can use `gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", ".*", gsub(".*", "", kind, fixed = TRUE), perl = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
vals <- attr(adist(kind, word,counts = TRUE), 'counts')[,,3]
ifelse(vals>0, 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE')
[1] "NEGATIVE" "POSITIVE" "NEGATIVE"
```

Comment: Using `adist` here is great but, frankly, this code is completely opaque because it favours cleverness over clarity. Using `ifelse` or something along these lines instead of implicit logical=>numeric conversion would dramatically improve readability, and using properly-named temporary variables would also help.

Comment: @KonradRudolph how exactly will `ifelse` work here? This is clearly a string comparison problem where one checks that all the letters in the kind string are in the word string in the same given order.  Could you please provide a solution with `ifelse`?

Comment: @Onyambu You’re implicitly converting the counts returned by `adist` to a local value. *That* is what I’m referring to. In other words, replace `c('NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE')[1 + !attr(adist(…), 'counts')[,,3]]` with `ifelse(attr(adist(…), 'counts')[, , 'sub'] > 0L, 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE')`. And as mentioned this becomes even more readable when introducing a variable name for the substitution count. — I love the cleverness of your solution but it’s code golf, and not readable/maintainable.